# flex 3 - canvas background visibility issue, how to place bg on top left corner

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

**update1** please read the updated para below
**update2** created a test app. figured out that the flex tries to place the bg in the center of the container (canvas). so the new question is "how to position bg image to the left top corner when the bg image is smaller than the canvas (parent). but still there is mystical puzzle unsolved which I am thinking is related to how flex places the child. please read update2 at bottom
**update3** workaround - not working

I am trying to figure out to fix the issue where the background image of a canvas is not appearing.

I have flex 3.5 app, I have set height and width to 648x1008

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            layout="absolute"
            width="1008" height="648"
```

in this I have a 3 child canvas components. all of them are added dynamically and positioned to 0,0, two canvas' height, width are set to 100%.

```
width="100%" height="100%"
```

my 3rd canvas comp is the main component which is quit larger (4096x4096). i have code to start and stop drag this canvas in mousedown and up handlers

```
        mouseDown="mouseDownHandler()" 
        mouseUp="mouseUpHandler()"
        width="{GameConfig.FULL_GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH}"
        height="{GameConfig.FULL_GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT}"
        backgroundImage="{GameResource.bg}"
```

dimensions defined in variables in GameConfig.as

```
    //game screen dimensions
    public static const FULL_GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH:int = 4096;
    public static const FULL_GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT:int = 4096;
```

bg class defined in variable in GameResource.as

```
    [Embed(source="../../../../assets/images/bg.jpg")]
    public static const bg:Class;
```

*background image path is perfect, I have verified by adding a dummy image to the problem canvas and set the same source ({GameResource.bg})*

**Now the problem is that the background image is not at all appearing**

Other two canvas doesnt have any background color they just have few components (buttons and images) positioned in bottom and top which means the problem canvas is not hidden behind the other canvas. **Most importantly the children inside the problem canvas are appearing**

I have created a dummy app which is working fine as excpeted

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
            height="600" width="800" layout="absolute"
            horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.fg.greenrev.config.GameResource;
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Canvas id="bg" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
           height="1600" width="4096"
           backgroundColor="0xccbbdd"
           backgroundImage="{GameResource.bg}"
           mouseDown="{bg.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(-3296,-1000,3296,1000))}" mouseUp="{bg.stopDrag()}">
</mx:Canvas>

</mx:Application>
```

can some one please help me.

**Update1:**
 I have just modified the code, I turned on scrolling policy of main application and I have removed the bgimage from problem canvas to its child canvas whos size is also same as problem canvas and now bg appears roughly at 2x (1400) of the app screen height and slightly to the right of the screen (around 200px). If move the bgimage to problem canvas it doesnt appear atall again. It seems like the problem with how/where flex adds the bgimage. I was assuming it adds at 0,0 but it looks like its not.

**Update2:**

I have tried created a dummy app simulating the scenario with dummy code. **I narrowed down the issue by changing the FULL_GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT to the actual size of the bg (1600)**. Earlier it was larger than the bg (more than 2.5x). Now the image is appearing properly. The issue seems to be with the flex trying to lay the image in the center of the canvas.

I could replicate the issue so that you can try this in your environment and see what is happening

**Main App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
            height="600" width="800" layout="absolute"
            creationComplete="init()">
            <!--horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"-->
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import _dummy.test1;
        import _dummy.test2;
        import _dummy.test3;

        import com.fg.greenrev.config.GameResource;

        private function init():void{

            var t1:test1 = new test1();
            addChild(t1);

            t1.init();

            var t2:test2 = new test2();
            addChild(t2);

            var t3:test3 = new test3();
            addChild(t3);

        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

** test1.mxml -  Child component (the problem 1)***

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.fg.greenrev.config.GameConfig;
        import com.fg.greenrev.config.GameResource;

        import mx.states.AddChild;

        public function init():void{

            var c1:test1Child = new test1Child();
            addChild(c1);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Label x="10" y="10" text="Test1"/>

</mx:Canvas>
```

*** test2.mxml - child2 (no problem) ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
       horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
       width="100%" height="100%"
       x="0" y="0">
<mx:Label x="96" y="0" text="Test2"/>

</mx:Canvas>
```

*** test3.mxml - child3 (no problem) ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
       horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
       width="100%" height="100%"
       x="0" y="0">
</mx:Canvas>
```

*** test1Child.mxml - child of child1 (no problem, but moving the bg from test1.mxml to here isnt making any difference in this test app but making diff in my originial app)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
       horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
       width="{GameConfig.FULL_GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH}"
       height="{GameConfig.FULL_GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT}"
       >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.fg.greenrev.config.GameConfig;
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Label x="390" y="0" text="Test1Child"/>

 </mx:Canvas>
```

As you can see test1 and test1Child are same size and larger (huge) than the main app
child2 and child3 are 100% width and height

replace FULL_GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH and FULL_GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT with 4096. have a dummy image of 4096x1600 and run the app you will see the bg is laid some where in the center (you can see the image if you scroll the app. now change the FULL_GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT to 1600 (size of the bg), bg is shown perfectly.

now there are two questions

q1) how to make the bg appear in the center of the parent when bg image is smaller than the container(parent/canvas)
q2) its actually puzzle, surprisingly the bg image is appearing to almost to the right corner (at around 4000px) when it is placed in problem canvas (in my original app, test1.mxml in dummy) but appearing properly when i moved the bg to its child (test1Child in the test app)

**update 3**: workaround not working

I have added this as the first line in the problem canvas, bg is appearing and it is covering remaining children. I knew adding it at first lines makes it first child meaning index = 0 meaning always stays back side but surprisingly, its not just making its' children canvas invisible but also occluding the other controls which are inside the other canvas. I have also tried to dynamically add the image using addChildAt(img,0) and also forecefully made the index to 0 by setChildIndex(img,0) but no use. Sick and tired

Comment: Can u tell me the size of the background image, did you tried debugging, and does it throws any error.

Comment: @sudharsanan its 4096x1600. it doent throw any kind of error

Comment: How about adding bindable metatag for image class?

Comment: please read the update2. i could continue if i get answer to "how to place the bg image to the top left corner of canvas/container"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working workaround

well i thought this woould work

```
<mx:Image x="0" y="0" source="{GameResource.bg}" mouseEnabled="false"/>
```

but for some reason it was occlding remaining controls and containers, despite it was added at the very first line (which makes ints displayindex = 0)

then I addeed this code to add them dynamically

```
            var img:Image = new Image();
            img.mouseEnabled = false;
            img.mouseChildren = false;
            img.source = GameResource.bg;

            addChildAt(img,0);
```

working like charm. BLOODY FLEX VERY UNPREDICTABLE